# Where to install Android SDK on Mac OS X?

Tags: android, configuration, macos

Where should the Android SDK be installed on Mac OS X?

Comment: I think that using `brew` to install it answers your question and also solves other possible issues like upgrading it. Check my answer below.

Comment: the **obvious, default, usual** location, **where it is installed by default** is simply ~/Library/Android/sdk/.  Where else would you possibly want it than there - and that's the default installation location.

Comment: On my OS X system with Android Studio, it was installed in `~/.android-sdk/` by default.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) the `android-sdk` has migrated from `homebrew/core` to `homebrew/cask`.

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
```

and install `android-sdk` using

```
brew install android-sdk --cask
```

You will have to add the `ANDROID_HOME` to profile (.zshrc or .bashrc)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

If you prefer otherwise, copy the package to

```
~/opt/local/android-sdk-mac
```

Comment: Unfortuantely this currently fails, because the licenses ar not automatically accepted. The installation just fails. `The following packages can not be installed since their licenses or those of the packages they depend on were not accepted:
  extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
  emulator
  tools
...
==> Exit status of failed command:
#<Process::Status: pid 34109 exit 1>`

Comment: It seems I could temporarily fix the install script: `brew cask edit android-sdk` I edited the preflight command. I modified `input : 'y'` to `input : 'y
y
y
y
y
y
y
'`
A newline between every `y`

Comment: @Pete This problem no longer exists in homebrew cask

Comment: this answer messed up my package. **Do not Use This**

Comment: @gmuraleekrishna `Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-cask /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-cask --depth=1` exited with 128.`

Comment: @DolDurma the problem seems to be with your homebrew. The git url is not supposed to have the second '-cask' at the end. Try again after  `brew tap homebrew/cask`

Answer (score 447):

The easiest (and standard) way to install Android SDK under OS X is to use `brew`.

`brew install android-sdk`

If you do not have homebrew, [here's how to get it](http://brew.sh).

This will install Android SDK into `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/` and, at this moment, this is the best location to install it.

Comment: @kalev it might be worth reporting that to Eclipse or IntelliJ, the IDEs should not be referencing the resolved Cellar directory which includes the version number. They should only reference `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`.

Comment: Homebrew rocks!

You can also run `android update sdk --no-ui` after installing with Homebrew to get the latest SDK release. The --no-ui option if you only use the CLI of course (i.e. with Cordova) - Win!

Comment: This works great. I am having problems with the permissions on other users, though. There, Android Studio refuses to start.

Comment: Just one folder deeper :) for me its /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1/

Comment: @AntonySastre that would be e.g., not i.e.. You can use the CLI with things other than Cordova.

Comment: this should be the best answer, not only for installation, its home-brew also help to update, uninstallation

Comment: This command was recommened to me.
brew cask install android-sdk

Comment: For me, it got installed at:  `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/`

Comment: Mine got installed at `/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

Answer (score 41):

When I installed Android Studio 1.0 it ended up in

> /Library/Android/sdk/

Comment: In my case it was in ~/Library/Android/sdk/

Comment: If anyone has trouble finding the `/Library` folder on Mac, the best way to do it is to open a Terminal, then type `open Library` in your `/~` folder, then drag & drop the SDK directory onto the file browser.

Answer (score 39):

My personal preference is to put it in `~/opt/local/android-sdk-mac` or /`Developer/android-sdk-mac` the latter being where Xcode and all the Apple Dev tools are held.

Comment: Accepted answer; although the others are true - the kit can be installed anywhere - this is in the spirit of my question and gives me something concrete to work with.  Thanks.

Comment: For future readers, do not store under /Developer/android-sdk-mac or anywhere under /Developer if you're on iOS 10.6, because when you upgrade to 10.7, Apple throws your /Developer directory in the .Trash

Comment: @James you mean OSX, not iOS ;)

Comment: installing with homebrew (see sorin's answer) is much nicer than dropping it in some random place in the filesystem.

Answer (score 33):

By default the android sdk installer path is `~/Library/Android/sdk/`

Answer (score 20):

You can install android-sdk in different ways

1. homebrew
   Install brew using command from [brew.sh](http://brew.sh)

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```

   Install `android-sdk` using

   ```
   brew install android-sdk
   ```

   Now `android-sdk` will be installed in `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
   ```
2. If you installed android studio following the [website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html),
   `android-sdk` will be installed in `~/Library/Android/sdk`

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
   ```

I think these defaults make sense and its better to stick to it

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "android-sdk"
It was migrated from `homebrew/core` to `homebrew/cask`.
`brew cask install android-sdk`

Answer (score 7):

From http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html, it seems that you can install the SDK anywhere, so long as you

1. "execute the android tool in the `<sdk>/tools/` folder"
2. Add the `<sdk>/tools` directory to your system path

More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at that page, but I'm really looking for some kind of consensus good place to put it.

Comment: The best place to put it is where you will remember where it is located - and no, I'm not being smarmy (or specious), it's just that this is a personal choice and typically not a professional one.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin; I appreciate your logic.  It's just that I don't have a  standard place where I put these things, and I'm interested to know what an unsurprising place would be for other developers.  There are a lot of standard places for things in unix - and the standards seem sometimes to be required by some software, that is, more than just convention.  I realize Macs are free-er, but would still like to conform to some kind of standard or convention.

Answer (score 6):

I just have mine in `MyUser/Documents/Development`.  I'm the only one that used my Mac, so I didn't need to worry about making it accessible system-wide.

Answer (score 4):

I put mine in /Developer/SDKs  I had to authenticate to do that…but since there's no consensus I thought that it sounded like a place I'd remember.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up placing my at ~/sdks/android-sdk-mac_x86. I like to keep all of my SDKs in one place and for me an sdk folder under my home directory makes the most sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
brew install android-sdk --cask
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 2):

I have been toying with this as well. I initially had it in my documents folder, but decided that didn't make 'philosophical' sense. I decided to create an Android directory in my home folder and place Eclipse and the Android SKK in there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is changing to required sdk in some android project the number of

> compileSdkVersion

in build.gradle file and you can install with the manager