# Android Hello World in IntelliJ 12 - Cannot find android.app.Activity class

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Please see below. I have a feeling I've got the SDKs configured incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I tried Googling for answers but no one had this exact problem.

Do I have the wrong Java version maybe? It seems like the two SDKs might be conflicting with each other.

I made this project via:

1. Create New Project
2. Android > Application Module
3. Defaults and Finish

[image: error in IntelliJ]

---

Edit: See screenshot. I got it working. All I did was create a new project and re-select the Android SDK. I'm still thinking it was because I added too many SDKs/JDKs the first time. I think all you need is the Android SDK and don't need to add the normal Java one too.

[image]

Comment: Correct you only need the Android SDK. In the "Project Structure" -> "Platform SettingS" -> "SDKs" you can set the Java SDK in the Android SDK options pane (use 1.6 or 1.5 not 1.7).

Answer (score 1):

I tried what for3st suggested to no avail at first, but i've heard other places that you should use JDK 1.6 for IntelliJ IDEA in other places, so you can do that [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u21-b07-oth-JPR%22here%22). Also, you set the SDK by going 'File'->"Project Structure" -> "Platform SettingS" -> "SDKs"

In the end, I also switched from Android 2.2 to 2.3.3 (api 10) and that got it to work. Don't have a good idea why it didn't work for 2.2, but since I just want a beginner's tutorial, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, but the conditions leading up to it are quite unusual.

I downloaded the Android SDK as a zipfile and unextracted it into `/opt`.

However, the permissions did not allow normal users to enter all directories or execute all files... so when IntelliJ indexed the SDK it only picked up the `res` jar... and never added the sources to the library path!

Deleting the SDK, fixing the permissions problem in the SDK, and creating a new reference in IntelliJ fixed it.

Comment: Same problem I was having. Thanks! Also, if you're on mac you can also install using brew. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677431/where-to-install-android-sdk-on-mac-os-x