# can't find android.Activity class intellij IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Yesterday my laptop got turned off, because I forget to plug it to the power source.

Now I turn on my laptop and see an error in the bottom of the Run windows, when I attempt to run my project:

> Error:Cannot find android.app.Activity class

And I tested this and this way can't solve my problem
[Android Hello World in IntelliJ 12 - Cannot find android.app.Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316370/android-hello-world-in-intellij-12-cannot-find-android-app-activity-class)

Edit:
i use this answer, and it's work for me:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369514/2003342

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe invalidate IDEA cache could help?
Files -> Invalidate cache and restart -> Invalidate and restart

Answer (score 3):

Faced similar problem. Tried restarting, it didn't work. But the problem occurred when I changed the installation path for SDKs. So reinstalled with default path, everything worked fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used IntelliJ in a while, I have had this problem before and it's usually a case of a missing reference *somewhere*.

Try removing the old Android SDK from the program and adding it back. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling everything, with a fresh SDK from the Google site. That should fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Download and reinstall. Simplest fix.