# Where does homebrew install android-sdk?

Tags: android, macos, homebrew

Where does homebrew install the android-sdk when you run the command:

```
brew cask install android-sdk
```

I want to be able to add it to the PATH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to install Android SDK on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677431/where-to-install-android-sdk-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: @RicardoParro did my answer help you with this?

Comment: FYI In order to install now you need to do `brew cask install android-sdk`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The installation folder of `android-sdk` is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/<VERSION>
```

Therefore, if you want to add it to PATH, you need to add the following line to ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/<VERSION>/tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/<VERSION>/platform-tools
```

Don't forget to replace `<VERSION>` with an installed version, just take a look inside of `android-sdk` folder to see what version you have installed.

Comment: The install is symlinked via the usual `/usr/local/` paths setup in the `$PATH` when initially setting up Homebrew--**so no special configuration is needed**. ``export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH``. @kornfridge note below ``brew info`` answer points out ``export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk``. **Using this approach instead of the one above allows update+upgrade without constantly editing the path/env.** Note too the path search order affects command use, so I have ``$PATH`` appended, not prepended.

Comment: As others have stated,  `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk` is the best option.

Comment: This is no longer true, since `android-sdk` was moved from `homebrew/core` to `caskroom/cask`. See my answer for more details of the changes.

Comment: this is all wrong, misleading, time-wasting babble and should be removed. it's in none of these places.

Answer (score 48):

## use `brew info --cask android-sdk`

after installing, you can get some basic information about what needs to be set and where:

```
› brew cask info android-sdk
...etc
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt (binary)
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools/bin/avdmanager
...etc

==> Caveats
We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for 
you. You can control android sdk packages via the sdkmanager command.
You may want to add to your profile:

  'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'
```

### notes

Prior to March 2017 you could run `brew info android-sdk`

Comment: actually `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk` is a symlink to ANDROID_HOME, so there's no need to provide new version every time sdk updates (as in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, brew has now changed where android-sdk is installed, so all of these older questions are no longer correct.

When installing via `brew cask install android-sdk`, you'll now be informed that you should add `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk` to your profile, and, indeed, that directory is now a symlink to the version android-sdk directory (currently `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/25.2.3`).

To summarise, add the following to your .profile/.bashrc/.whatever:

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools`

Comment: Thanks @Endareth, but I have 1 issue - my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_HOME all point to the same location as mentioned above and when I create emulator it gets created inside /usr/local/share/android-sdk/.android/avd even after I explicitly provide different path (Users/me/.android/sdk) to avdmanager create command. Any idea what could be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 11):

You would be better off using the symlink that Homebrew creates to ANDROID_HOME, as it will always be the newest version:

`/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/`

So your PATH would be:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools`

Answer (score 1):

in my machine, at `/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

My Homebrew installation (brew install --cask android-platform-tools) use this Path:

/usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/30.0.0/platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew installs things in the Cellar:

`/usr/local/Cellar`