# Visual studio team services Cordova build error

Tags: cordova, ionic2, azure-devops

I am trying to use the Cordova Build task in order to build an Ionic 2 app for android however i am receiving the following error.

`TypeError: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function`

The configuration i am using is as follows:

Platform: android
Configuration: Release
Target Archives:
Cordova Version: 6.3.1

I have found this error mentioned on here before: [Cordova Error using Cordova-Android 6.2.0 - getFileResources is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195668/cordova-error-using-cordova-android-6-2-0-getfileresources-is-not-a-function)

However the accepted answer is not implementable within visual studio team services as far as i am concerned.

The application is known to build successfully with the following configuration:
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1

Gulp version: CLI version 1.2.2

Gulp local:

Ionic Framework Version: 3.3.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1

Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7

OS:

Node Version: v7.8.0

NPM: 4.2.0

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with 7.0.1 Cordova?

Comment: unfortunately not, time pressure got the better of me so i decided to use ionic commands to build the project

Comment: You can share the detail build log here.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue with Cordova 6.3.1, using 7.0.1 version instead, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2015 Cordova project I got the same error while doing iOS remote build.

Simply deleting the following line of code from the config.xml file (VS 2015 Cordova project) solved the issue for me.

```
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
```

May help someone.