# cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function

Tags: android, apache, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having a deployment error when I'm trying to deploy my project to Android Emulator. The error says:

```
cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function
```

I tried to search net and tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43205023/2637261) but still no luck. Can someone help me? Thanks!

PS: System Information

```
Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.5.7
Cordova-Android: 6.3.1
Cordova: 8.0.0
Gradle: 4.6
```

Comment: i have same problem, by luck did you get any way ?

Comment: @DeepakPatel have you tried the solution below? I fixed this before the answer came in here. Unfortunately I haven't updated this thread. But will look again how did I fixed this as soon as I got to my computer. Best of luck!

Comment: Not sure but I found strange problem with the recent version of Visual studio(2017 - 15.7.6) , after installing global cordova with latest, automatically VS has removed current installed version from directory but as per VS standard both version should be there

Answer (score 4):

This problem basically comes from outdated Cordova version. Please use the below methods to resolve that.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```

Then remove your platforms folder and add it again with below command.

```
cordova platform add android --save
```