# Original error: Could not find 'aapt' in ["/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt"] Appium - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, automation, appium

I am currently trying to learn about Appium Automated Testing. Everything is setup perfectly on my Mac.

All my environmental variables are set up correctly :

> export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk
>
> export
>   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

However when I run the eclipse program, eclipse throws an error saying:

> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'aapt' in
>   ["/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/aapt","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/bin/aapt"].
>   Do you have Android Build Tools installed at
>   '/usr/local/share/android-sdk'?

So my question is why eclipse is looking for Android SDK tools in usr/local , my sdk tools are located in

> /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk.

How can I tell eclipse to look for the appt,adb, etc in my User folder and not the admin usr folder.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable has `/usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/aapt` entry and it is resolved **before** your additions of the `ANDROID_HOME` variable.

So either [remove that Android SDK which lives under `/usr/local/share/android-sdk/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209083/where-does-homebrew-install-android-sdk) from your operating system like:

```
brew cask uninstall android-sdk
```

or amend your PATH variable definition so your "good" Android SDK installation goes **before** anything else like:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

See [Appium Java Code examples](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for more information regarding proper setup of Appium environment. You might also want to check the integrity of the infrastructure setup using [`appium-doctor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor)

```
appium-doctor --android
```

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with on MacOS Catalina 10.15.3, Appium 1.10.1, Appium Doctor v.1.13.0 trying to set up Android with Appium.

Make sure you are changing the correct file. You have 3 possible locations.

**~/.bash_profile**

**~/.profile**

**~/.zshrc**

I was editing my **~/.bash_profile** instead of **~/.zshrc** you can have a situation where you are setting the correct path but not in the right file.

If your trying to get going with Android Appium in Mac here is what I put in my **~/.zshrc** at the bottom

```
# Android Paths for Appium
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/**PUT_YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE_WITHOUT_STARS**/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Also if you don't want to edit in a terminal-based editor use the following command to open the files in a text editor.

`open -e .bash_profile`

`open -e .zshrc`

`open -e .profile`

After editing do not forget to save.

Quit your Terminal.

Run `Appium_Doctor`

The following post helped me out a lot when setting up my Appium

**appium-workshop/Appium Mac Installation Instructions**

https://github.com/isonic1/appium-workshop/blob/master/Appium%20Mac%20Installation%20Instructions.md

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system-wide eclipse installation, it usually won't read your environment variables from your `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile`, but from `/etc/environment`.

If you don't want to modify this file, or if it doesn't exist on a Mac, then you can always set the variables at a project level. This is done in the "Environment" tab of the configuration (run, debug, external tools,...) you're running within Eclipse, like this:

[image]