# Android Studio 3.0.1 for Mac not opening/installing SDK

Tags: macos, android-studio, ide, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I've downloaded [Android Studio 3.0.1](https://developer.android.com/) for Mac and as I started it, it showed the splash screen for loading but did nothing else relevant (in the case, means showing the menu for starting/opening/importing projects).

[image: Android Studio frozen Startup]

After some research, I found that I could bypass this screen if I change the `idea.properties` and put on the following line:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

After that I can now reach the SDK Manager window, but no SDK update sites, platforms or tools shows up.

I'm running macOS X High Sierra 10.13.2.

Can anyone help me on installing the SDK tools and platforms?

Edit:

SDK Platform Screenshot

[image: SDK Platform Screenshot]

SDK Tools Screenshot

[image: SDK Tools Screenshot]

SDK Update Sites Screenshot

[image: SDK Update Sites Screenshot]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the SDK manager window?

Comment: Sure, here they are: [SDK Platform](https://imgur.com/4Csupgf), [SDK Tools](https://imgur.com/LOcN8tR), and [SDK Update Sites](https://imgur.com/WdDPzH6). I tried force-use https but didn't work either. I'm not on a restrictive connection (corporate firewalls or any other network restrictions. It's a home connection)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with those screenshots.

Comment: In the SDK manager window, there is a textbox labeled "Android SDK Location". What do you get when you click "Edit"? Is it a file chooser dialog?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and install it again. It should have downloaded the Android SDK components while installing but it doesn't seem to be the case. Make sure your connected to the internet during the installation, and once the installation is completed, ensure that they have been downloaded by checking the default Android SDK location on MacOS. Then try opening Android Studio without needing to change any config.

Comment: It didn't work out. I downloaded the binaries again, installed again. The installation process is a simple copy-paste into Applications folder. Despite the first run bypass, there's no option for checking/changing the default Android SDK location.

Comment: Could you confirm if the Android SDK was downloaded and is available for access from the command line? If not then I suggest do download and setup the Android SDK alone, ensure that they are in the PATH env variable, and then try opening Android Studio again.

Comment: Here is a link to the Android SDK MacOS installation steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43797501/2949966. And as a side note, double check if Java is setup properly as well, although I believe it comes packaged with Android Studio by default so there could be no need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

By the time this question was made, there was no solution.
The OS requirements were Mac OS High Sierra up to 10.12. There was no Android Studio for Mac OS 10.13.

Currently there is a version that supports Mac OS 10.13.

edit: also, I found out that [permission problems](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538) may cause unexpected behavior of some apps (Visual Studio Code also broke). After the permissions check, the software worked like a charm.