# Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (arm64 version) cannot find Android SDK location

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, apple-m1, android-studio-arctic-fox

I am using m1 macbook pro (apple silicon).
currently I got unintalled my old version Android Studio (intel ver) and reinstalled Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (arm64 version).

after I reinstalled, at SDK Manager, it cannot find SDK location.
and when I press 'Edit' button and press 'install' button, my screen is going to install screen but never change.
[my SDK Manager screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZq8.jpg)

When I uninstalled my old version Android Studio, I used this commands.

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.gradle  
rm -Rf ~/.android  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*  
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/
```

and here is my flutter doctor -v's result

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm, locale
    ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/seunghyun/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (7 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: You Hae to install android SDK visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/43797501/12100915

Answer (score 0):

```
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
```

I would recommend trying to re-install android studio first. If that doesn't work then try reading this post: [[tag][!] Android Studio (not installed) , when run flutter doctor while Android Studio installed on machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647791/tag-android-studio-not-installed-when-run-flutter-doctor-while-android)

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I moved my Android Studio from download folder to Application folder, and that message's problem is now solved.